# Let $f(x)=x^n+p_1x^{n-1}+p_2x^{n-2}+ ...+p_n.$ The positive roots of the equation $f(x)=0$ do not exceed $\sqrt[r]{p}+1$ where $-p$ is the greatest

Tags: inequality, polynomials, proof-explanation, systems-of-equations

Let $$f(x)=x^n+p_1x^{n-1}+p_2x^{n-2}+ ...+p_n.$$The positive roots of the equation $f(x)=0$ do not exceed $\sqrt[r]{p}+1$ where $-p$ is the greatest negative coefficient and $p_r$ is the first negative coefficient of $f(x)$.

The proof given is as follows :

> Any value of $x$ that make $x^n>p(x^{n-r}+x^{n-r-1}+...+1)$ will make $f(x)$ positive . Let $x>1$ . Then, $x^n>p(x^{n-r}+x^{n-r-1}+...+1)$ will hold if $x^n>p\frac{x^{n-r+1}-1}{x-1}$ i.e , if $x^n>p\frac{x^{n-r+1}}{x-1}$ i.e if $x^{r-1}(x-1)>p$ i.e if $(x-1)^r>p$ i.e if $x>\sqrt[r]{p}+1$.

However, in the proof given above I am not getting how are they asserting the fact"Any value of $x$ that make $x^n>p(x^{n-r}+x^{n-r-1}+...+1)$ will make $f(x)$ positive" . I do not get how they are drawing this conclusion .

Comment: Using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csqrt%5Br%5D%7Bp%7D%2B1%24&p=1), I found this [AoPS topic](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1517470p9045635) with a similar question **but** it states that $-p$ is the greatest **negative** coefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all coefficients are positive, there will be no positive roots. So some of the coefficients are negative. The first negative coefficient is $p_r$. Let us assume $p$ positive. We also assume $-p$ as the greatest negative coefficient.

$x^n+p_1x^{n-1}+p_2x^{n-2}+ ...+p_r x^{n-r} + \cdots +p_n \ge x^n+ p_r x^{n-r} + \cdots +p_n > x^n - p(x^{n-r}+x^{n-r-1}+...+1)$

The first inequality is true because all coefficients till $p_r$ are positive (and $x$ is positive).

The second inequality is true because if we made every negative coefficient equal to the largest negative coeff, we get the worst case.

So now if $x^n - p(x^{n-r}+x^{n-r-1}+...+1) > 0$ then surely $f(x) > 0$.

The rest of the proof follows.

Comment: Actually what is meant by the largest negative coefficient? Does it mean if $(p_1,p_2,p_3,...,p_n)$  (say) is an arbitary set of negative integers then the greatest negative integer is $p_i$ such that $p_i\geq p_j$, $\forall p_j\in A$. Or does the greatest negative integer means : $p_i$ such that $|p_i|\geq |p_j|$? In which sense it is used?

Comment: in the first sense

Comment: I missed the word "negative " in my original post . Nevertheless, I have edited it. But if the greatest negative coefficient is not used in sense of magnitudes , then how does your second inequality stays valid? I dont get it...

Comment: if u check this: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1517470p9045635 then u see that user SDMM clarifies the thing...so I think it must be the second sense...seems kinda obvious though...

Comment: sorry, in the second sense is right. The wording is certainly not clear. Thanks

Comment: No problem . Infact, I should be the one thanking you...